# Markdown help in documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, markdown

With documentation, [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) has been introduced to nicely structure information. I'm having some trouble escaping `|` character inside table cells while I was editing [Selectors topic in CSS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/611/selectors/4044/overview).

If use backquotes like

```
`|`
```

It is rendered as column. When I tried to escape | like \| without backticks, it is properly escaped but if I put backticks around, I get `\|`.

Is there a workaround for this?